How to fix "Element implicitly has an 'any' type" when indexing JSON object with dynamic keys in TypeScript?
I'm working on a React component that renders a conversation based on a given conversation ID. The conversations data is stored in a local JSON file, but I'm encountering a TypeScript error at line 18 Conversations[ConversationId] when I try to access the conversation using a dynamic key. The error states:
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ Conversations: { "Conversation-0": { conversationName: string; userList: string[]; Messages: ({ id: string; SenderId: string; Message: string; MessageContent?: undefined; } | { id: string; SenderId: string; MessageContent: string; Message?: undefined; })[]; }; "Conversation-1": { ...; }; }; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ Conversations: { "Conversation-0": { conversationName: string; userList: string[]; Messages: ({ id: string; SenderId: string; Message: string; MessageContent?: undefined; } | { id: string; SenderId: string; MessageContent: string; Message?: undefined; })[]; }; "Conversation-1": { ...; }; }; }'.

Here is the code content:
import { useState } from 'react';
import Message from '@/app/Components/Message/Message';

interface ConversationProps {
    ConversationId: string;
}

interface MessageType {
    id: string;
    senderId: string;
    MessageContent: string;
}

import Conversations from './temp/tempdata.json';

function Conversation({ ConversationId }: ConversationProps) {
    const [MessagesList, UpdateMessageList] = useState(
        Conversations[ConversationId].Messages.map(
            (id: string, senderId: string, MessageContent: string) => ({
                id: id,
                senderId: senderId,
                MessageContent: MessageContent,
            })
        )
    );

    return (
        <div id='ConversationContainer'>
            {MessagesList.map(
                (id: string, SenderId: string, MessageContent: string) => (
                    <Message
                        key={`Message-${id}`}
                        senderId={SenderId}
                        message={MessageContent}
                    />
                )
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Conversation;

And here is the json file content (tempdata.json):
{
    "Conversations": {
        "Conversation-0": {
            "conversationName": "The first ever conversation on this app.",
            "userList": ["0", "1"],
            "Messages": [
                {
                    "id": "0",
                    "SenderId": "0",
                    "Message": "Hi, this is the initial message sent by user 0 to first ever conversation."
                },
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "SenderId": "1",
                    "MessageContent": "And this is another user's initial message sent by user 1."
                }
            ]
        },
        "Conversation-1": {
            "conversationName": "The second conversation that ever created.",
            "userList": ["0", "2"],
            "Messages": [
                {
                    "id": "0",
                    "SenderId": "0",
                    "Message": "Hi, this is the initial message for conversation id 1 from user 0."
                },
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "SenderId": "2",
                    "MessageContent": "And this is user 2's initial message."
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

The error happens when trying to dynamically index Conversations using the ConversationId. I'm aware that TypeScript doesn't allow indexing with arbitrary string keys without an index signature. How can I fix this error while keeping the strict typing intact? Should I modify the structure of my JSON or adjust how I index it?

The error shows that the indexed object is  {Conversations: {/*value*/}} and your code seems to be indexing the value object mapped to "Conversations" key (the one with the Conversations- key prefixes). You should change your import statement to import { Conversations } from './temp/tempdata.json' to destructure the value from the json module. Refer to this stackblitz for correct application of Array.map method and fix your code.
